# Why am I receiving the wrong bits when sending data through UART on Basys3 FPGA?

Tags: verilog, fpga, uart, vivado

My goal is to send data from my Basys3 board to my laptop, and I am using UART to do so. The Verilog code I wrote successfully sends data to my computer, but I am receiving the wrong bits.

Below you can see the results of my simulation when sending 01010101, which corresponds to the letter U's ASCII encoding. As the markers show, I am sending a bit around every (1/9600)s, so after 10 bits are sent, time will be at 1041.66us. My timing is a bit off, but the maximum acceptable baud rate error is 2.5%, and my rate is well within this range.

[As you can see, I start with pulling TX LOW to start the transmission, then I send my data, starting with the LSB. I end the transmission by pulling TX HIGH, and the line remains HIGH in its IDLE state.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQakB.png)

When sending the same data 01010101 and viewing the results in Pyserial, I see the following:
[This is not the desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnxHf.png)

The same data is being sent consistently (the letter A, along with some additional bits), but I am not sure why they are not the correct results. Below shows the symbols that are printed on the PuTTy terminal corresponding to this data:
[Symbols being A and something else I am not sure of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7QNk.png)

Below is my code and constraints file. I am not sure what changes I should make because the simulation looks good to me. On the computer's end, I set the baud rate to 9600, 8 bits, 1 stop bit, and no parity bit for both PuTTy and Pyserial, so I do not think I made a mistake there either:

Design Source:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Company: 
// Engineer: 
// 
// Create Date: 05/24/2023 04:33:54 PM
// Design Name: 
// Module Name: TopUART
// Project Name: 
// Target Devices: 
// Tool Versions: 
// Description: 
// 
// Dependencies: 
// 
// Revision:
// Revision 0.01 - File Created
// Additional Comments:
// 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


module TopUART#(parameter cycle_BRG = 5208, idle = 2'b00, loading = 2'b01, sending = 2'b11, done = 2'b10)(
input clk, input [7:0] data_send, input transmit, output Txd
    );
    
    reg [13:0] BRG_counter = 0;
    reg [9:0] bit_counter = 0;
    reg BRG_SET;            //set to 1 every (1/9600) seconds
    reg BRG_SET_tracker;     //used so that I can set BRG_SET in two always blocks
    
    reg [1:0] state = 0;
    reg load = 0;
    reg shift = 0;
    reg clear = 0;
    reg Txd = 1;
    reg [9:0] shiftright_register = 0;
    
   //BRG for UART
    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        if(BRG_counter == cycle_BRG)
            begin
                BRG_SET <= 1;
                BRG_counter <= 0;
            end
         else
            begin
                BRG_counter <= BRG_counter + 1;
                BRG_SET <= 0;
            end
    end
    
    //controller for UART
    always@(posedge clk)
    begin
       case(state) 
            idle: //waiting for transmit button to be pressed
            begin
                if(transmit)
                begin
                    state <= loading;
                    load <= 1;
                    shift <= 0;
                    clear <= 0;
                    Txd <= 1;
                end
                
                else
                begin
                    state <= idle;
                    load <= 0;
                    shift <= 0;
                    clear <= 0;
                    Txd <= 1;
                end
            end 
            
            loading: //button was pressed, keeping load signal high until BRG has been set so that data path can update the shift register
            begin
                if(BRG_SET)
                begin
                    state <= sending;
                    load <= 0;
                    shift <= 1;
                    clear <= 0;
                    Txd <= 1;
                end
                
                else
                begin
                    state <= loading;
                    load <= 1;
                    shift <= 0;
                    clear <= 0;
                    Txd <= 1;
                end
            end
            
            sending: //send data until 10 bits have been sent on TX line
            begin
                if(bit_counter == 10)
                begin
                    state <= done;
                    load <= 0;
                    shift <= 0;
                    clear <= 1;
                    Txd <= 1;
                end
                else
                begin
                    state <= sending;
                    load <= 0;
                    shift <= 1;
                    clear <= 0;
                    Txd <= shiftright_register[0];
                end
            end
           
            done: //once 10 bits set, keep clear high and wait for BRG_SET to become 1 so that data path can reset the bit counter and BRG counter
            begin
                if(BRG_SET)
                begin
                    state <= idle;
                    load <= 0;
                    shift <= 0;
                    clear <= 0;
                    Txd <= 1;
                end
                else
                begin
                    state <= done;
                    load <= 0;
                    shift <= 0;
                    clear <= 1;
                    Txd <= 1;
                end
            end  
       endcase 
    end
    
    //data path for UART
    always @(posedge BRG_SET)
    begin
        if(load)
        begin
            shiftright_register <= {1'b1, data_send, 1'b0};
            bit_counter <= 0;
        end
        else if(shift)
        begin
            shiftright_register <= shiftright_register >> 1;
            bit_counter <= bit_counter +1;    
        end
        else if(clear)
        begin
            bit_counter <= 0; 
        end    
    end
endmodule
```

Constraints:

```
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {data_send[7]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {data_send[6]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {data_send[5]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {data_send[4]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {data_send[3]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {data_send[2]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {data_send[1]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {data_send[0]}]

set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {transmit}]

set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {Txd}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN W13 [get_ports {data_send[7]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W14 [get_ports {data_send[6]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V15 [get_ports {data_send[5]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W15 [get_ports {data_send[4]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W17 [get_ports {data_send[3]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W16 [get_ports {data_send[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V16 [get_ports {data_send[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V17 [get_ports {data_send[0]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN T17 [get_ports {transmit}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN A18 [get_ports {Txd} ]



set_property PACKAGE_PIN W5 [get_ports clk]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports clk]
create_clock -period 10.000 -name sys_clk_pin -waveform {0.000 5.000} -add [get_ports clk]
```

**Edit:** This is the testbench I used to simulate this design:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Company: 
// Engineer: 
// 
// Create Date: 05/25/2023 09:53:23 AM
// Design Name: 
// Module Name: TopUARTTestbench
// Project Name: 
// Target Devices: 
// Tool Versions: 
// Description: 
// 
// Dependencies: 
// 
// Revision:
// Revision 0.01 - File Created
// Additional Comments:
// 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


module TopUARTTestbench(

    );
   
    reg clk = 0;
    always #10 clk = ~clk;
    reg [7:0] data_send;
    reg transmit;
    wire Txd;
    TopUART x (clk, data_send, transmit, Txd);
    
    initial
    begin
        #20
        transmit = 1; #30;
        transmit = 0;
        data_send = 8'b01010101;
    end
endmodule
```

**Edit:** I want to note that I changed the code to count to exactly 10416 cycles per bit by setting `cycle_BRG = 10416`. When using 10417, I noticed that my MSB was always being read as a 1 by my laptop. This may be due to the computer missing the final data bit when sampling and reading the stop bit as my final bit.

Comment: @Mikef Sorry for the late reply, but I have added the testbench. No, I did not use a clock buffer nor constraints. I simply used a register to drive the clock, and I toggled its value every 10 nanoseconds.

Comment: @Mikef Got it. At the moment I am unsure about how to make a clock buffer, but I will look into it, and I will also add timing constraints. Regarding the constraint for the clock, I accidentally missed it when copying the file in. I have updated the code now.

Comment: No... I definitely want a 100MHz clock because that is the only clock frequency the Basys3 supports. Because I had a slower frequency clock signal in my simulation, I made the mistake of sending bits at twice the speed I should have been. I have now corrected my code to send at the correct baud rate, and I am getting the desired results. I will still look into the suggestions you made earlier for future projects, and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to consider for debug:

- According to this post [basys-3](https://forum.digilent.com/topic/681-creating-a-25-mhz-clock-on-the-basys-3/) the basys-3 board uses a 100 MHz clock.  The testbench codes the clock as `always #10 clk = ~clk1` which will create a 50MHz clock.  If the testbench results look correct, perhaps there is a factor of 2 error somewhere in the design.
- I don't see a bufg instance in the design.  If this is all the code you have then the clock is being distributed on local routing.  Local routing will have timing skew from flop to flop that is significant enough to cause ordinary digital design structures like counters & shift-registers to not behave as expected.  Inserting a bufg where the clock enters the part is the solution.  Internet search 'Xilxnx bufg' for more.
- Recommend using a clock constraint on the clock (constrain the bufg output), and reviewing the timing report generated by the tools after each build to verify that the design meets timing.  This becomes more of an issue and is essential as the design gets larger and the %utilization increases.